# "Entendre bien devenir"?

Tags: sens

I was listening to an RFI podcast and the transcript had this sentence:

> Moscou, rappelle le journal Le Croix, "menace de couper le robinet", si bien que l'Europe "se rue sur le gaz américain" et les États-Unis entendent bien devenir leader mondial en matière  d'exportation de gaz naturel liquéfié.

What does "entendre bien devenir" mean? I did not find a meaning that matched up on linguee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The US intention is to become and stay the word top LNG exporter.

[TLFI](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entendre)

> **Entendre**
> [...]
> **III.−** Domaine de la *volition*, dans la *langue soutenue*. Avoir une certaine conception de quelque chose et vouloir faire partager son point de vue à autrui.
> [...]
> **B.−** [Le complément est un infinitif] Avoir la ferme intention, la volonté arrêtée de faire une chose. *Il [Fred] sait qu'à sa majorité il sera duc de Nevers, et il entend porter haut ce titre et ce nom* (Gyp, *Monsieur Fred*, 1891, p. 7):
> 31. *Et Françoise, en bonne et honnête servante qui entend faire respecter son maître comme elle le respecte elle-même, s'était drapée de cette majesté qui ennoblit les entremetteuses dans les tableaux des vieux maîtres, ...* Proust, *La Prisonnière*, 1922, p. 141.

Comment: Oh, so it not only means "hear" but "intend." Okay. I should use TLFI more and Linguee less, it seems to be more comprehensive. I've always resisted because it's ... a bit dense, but such is life.

Comment: Yes, it can mean "understand" too, a polysemic verb.